# Parsley validate not work after change value from dom

Tags: javascript, parsley.js

I have validated my form on submit, there is a **data-parsley-error-message** show because I have not filled in the required input, but if required input keyup the **data-parsley-error-message** will disappear

The problem is, when I change the value from the dom, **data-parsley-error-message** still shown. I have to add

> data-parsley-trigger="change"

But it still does not work.

Detailed code: [`here`](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JaNmPN)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set a value via Javascript, you should then trigger an `input` event and a `change` event to mimic what would happen if the user had changed it herself.

`Parsley` listens to the `input` event by default.